# How to supply a microphone with plug-in-power via TRS or TRRS plug?

Tags: amplifier, audio, microphone

I would like to use a Rode VideoMicro microphone requiring low-voltage phantom power, or plug-in power, on a device which does not supply plug-in-power. There seem to be commercial options, though I would like to DIY a tiny, cheap version for my use-case.

What circuit is needed to supply the microphone with the needed 1.5-5v? Does either of these circuits below work?

[image: Plug-in-power diagram]

[image: Aviation-headset adapter]

Comment: Yes............. but the pullup R controls DC output AND gain

Comment: Could you update the question with links to the sources of the diagrams?  The top one looks familiar-- I think I encountered it before.

Answer (score 1):

Circuit 1 will supply less than 0.5mA, and most electret microphones are specified as consuming up to 0.5mA.  Replacing the 6k8 resistor with 2k2 (a rather typical load impedance for electrets) will likely be a better fit.  There will be a DC offset to the amplifier input; most amplifiers don't mind.  However, don't plug the mic in and out with the amplifier on (when it is not perfectly muted) or you'll get a bang like anything.

Circuit 2 has a rather brutal load resistance and does not do a lot for sieving low-impedance noise from USB power.  You want to bump that resistor to 2k2 and add maybe a 100ohms resistor between USB power and the 330µF capacitor.  Putting two capacitors in series like that seems weird: a single 10uF should do about the same.  Hypothetically one can put two electrolytics in "antiseries" (one with reversed polarity) in order to deal with DC offsets of either sign, but since the mic signal is already DC biased, that seems unnecessary.

With 10 µF of blocking and a signal starting around 20 Hz (say), the input impedance of the amp should not be below 800 ohm.  But it would be kind of unusual for it to be.

Answer (score 0):

The top circuit does NOT remove DC from the signal, which might not be appreciated by some preamp inputs.

The lower one looks more correct but you don't really need back to back electrolyticss. Better is this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fG1zbO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You might need to play around with resistor values a bit. The second 1k resistor keeps the output at 0VDC and helps prevent annoying noises when you plug in.

Note that this is one of two channels, you need to repeat this complete circuit for both L and R channels (it's a stereo mic with unbalanced output, [see datasheet](https://edge.rode.com/pdf/page/122/modules/5221/Asset_Pack_Datasheet_VideoMicro_02_FA.pdf) ).

Answer (score -2):

Did you already try with [3.5mm TRRS Audio Jack Breakout](https://protosupplies.com/product/trrs-audio-jack-breakout/)?

It's simple, there are only 4 pins

SLEEVE = Ground -> Ground
RING2 = Typically Microphone or video channel -> A0
RING1 = Audio RIGHT channel -> A1
TIP = Audio LEFT channel -> A2

Comment: I don't understand. While I have two of these, they are just a break-out. In order to use this microphone, plug-in-power is needed. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phantom_power#Other_microphone_powering_techniques and https://www.makerhart.com/product_d.php?lang=en&tb=1&id=7

Comment: @Riley the makerhart product you linked is overkill for your application, since it also includes 48V phantom power, which is much more expensive to implement than plug-in power.

Comment: This answer does not give an answer to the asked question. The plug can be used for making physical connections to the mic pins, but it does not help with what kind of circuitry is needed to make it work.